# How Can I automate clicking a button that only works when manually clicked?

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, automation, pyautogui

I need to automate uploading a file to a website. I am using Selenium, and I am able to navigate through the site and select the file input I want from a drive on my computer. The only piece that does not work is clicking the Upload button.

```
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'P:/_Public/ScheduledTasks/SeleniumDriver/chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get("https://client.schwabct.com?sId=MTUyMTM")
        username = driver.find_element_by_name("userName")
        username.clear()
        username.send_keys(<userid>)
        password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
        password.clear()
        password.send_keys(<pw>)
        driver.find_element_by_name("submitButton").click() 
        driver.get("https://client.schwabct.com/uploadData.action?currentApplication=87&currentRole=1&currentTab=16&currentModule=262&reset=Y")
        driver.find_element_by_name("submitButton").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        upload_options = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("slctValue"))
        upload_options.select_by_value("SECURITY_CHECKLIST")
        fileinput = driver.find_element_by_id('uploadData_uploadDataInfo_fileUpload')
        fileinput.send_keys(r"P:\_Public\Tamarac\Extracts\Upload_to_SCT\sct_upload_file.csv")
        d = driver.find_element_by_id("isIgnoreHeaderId").click()
        upload = driver.find_element_by_id("uploadButton").click()
```

I can run all the code just before the final button click, and it DOES upload the file if I then click the button manually. It gives an error when I try to automate the final button click. So the button is getting clicked, but the website does not recognize the file. The error text given by the website is "Cannot find file sct_upload_file.csv or file is empty."

I have tried switching to pyautogui right before the final button click to click on an image of the button. This also clicks the button, but it produces the same error as clicking the button with Selenium, even when using natural mouse movements through pyautogui to slowly move the mouse over the button and then click it.

[HTML from the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvZb8.png)

I have also tried using ActionChains to click the button. Again, I am able to click it, but I get the same error.

I have tried just selecting the element and using "upload.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)" on the subsequent line. It clicks the button, but I get the same error.

I have also tried moving the focus to the button, by sending TAB keys and by using switch_to, and then sending a RETURN key, but I have not been able to get the focus to actually move to the button.

When the final button is clicked the web page changes to a type of "wait while the file is uploaded" message.

[Data is being processed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtmsT.png)

The page then changes again to display the error message.

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFqBy.png)

The URL does not change. It is "https://client.schwabct.com/uploadData.action" for each page.

Comment: What is the error that is returned?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the HTML as code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. How much code to you need to see? Posting an expanded version of everything in the screenshot would be very long.

Comment: According to the error, the file path is wrong or the csv file is empty. You would not get the error if the upload button was not clicked successfully.

Comment: Thanks, Jortega. The csv file definitely has data, and the file path must be correct because when I run the code to the point just before the last line and then click the button with my finger on my mouse it works without error. I get the same "Data is being processed" screen when I manually click as with an automated click. I just does not recognize the file or file path with the automated click.

Comment: How about you try - example `upload = driver.find_element_by_id("uploadButton")` Then `upload.click()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstion 0m3r. That gave the same error as before. Is it possible there is security built into the website I am accessing that prevents automated uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself. The code in the question was actually indented under a "with" statement that opened the csv file that was being uploaded. Moving the code out of the "with" statement, closing the csv file, allowed it to work without error.